# Docker Linux Container Kernel Update

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, python-importlib

I created linux ubuntu container and I tired to run python script.

But it raises this error:

```
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:228: RuntimeWarning: Linux supports fsync/fdsync with io_submit since 4.18 but current kernel 4.15.0-55-generic doesn't support it. Related calls will have no effect.
```

How can I update ubuntu kernel which is inside docker container?

There is dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:21.04
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get dist-upgrade -y

RUN apt-get install python3.9 -y
RUN apt-get install python3-pip -y
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: How can I update ubuntu kernel which is inside docker container?

Comment: Look [here](https://forums.docker.com/t/dockerfile-run-apt-get-install-all-packages-at-once-or-one-by-one) and [here](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/).  1) You *cannot* upgrade a kernel like you're attempting, 2) You should generally have a *single* "RUN" command in your Dockerfile.

Comment: There is no kernel inside a Docker container; it uses the host's kernel.

Comment: I just started using docker so I'm a little bit ignorant thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot upgrade kernel *inside docker container* - the whole point
of using Docker containers in contrary to virtualization is that you
use the same kernel that your underlying OS does. You have to upgrade
your operating system kernel to fix this problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You are king.